# Regular expressions. Match specific word between two words

Tags: c#, regex

I use C#. I have a string:

```
wordA wordB wordC wordB wordD
```

I need to match all occurrences of wordB between wordA and wordD. 
I use lookahead and lookbehind to match everything between wordA and worD like this:

```
(?<=wordA)(.*?)(?=wordD)
```

But something like

```
(?<=wordA)(wordB)(?=wordD)
```

matches nothing. 
What would be the best way to match all occurrences of wordB between wordA and wordD?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to capture the word (since it's surrounded by parentheses). If that's the case, you could just as well use the more generic variant `\bfirst\b.*\b(second)\b.*\bthird\b` illustrated [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SUYwrQ/2). It works with most regex flavors :) The difference is that this *matches* everything from the first word to the third, but *captures* only the second one. This may be unwanted behavior and if so, the look-around approach given by @WiktorStribiżew does it. Other than being more generic, I don't think this has anything on Wiktors approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `.*?` into the lookarounds:

```
(?<=wordA.*?)wordB(?=.*?wordD)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DwordA.*%3F%29wordB%28%3F%3D.*%3FwordD%29&i=wordA%20wordB%20wordC%20wordB%20wordD)

Now, the pattern means:

- `(?<=wordA.*?)` - (a positive lookbehind) requires the presence of `wordA` followed with any 0+ chars (as few as possible) immediately before...
- `wordB` - word B
- `(?=.*?wordD)` - (a positive lookahead) requires the presence of any 0+ chars (as few as possible) followed with a `wordD` after them (so, it can be right after `wordB` or after some chars).

If you need to account for multiline input, compile the regex with `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag so that `.` could match a newline symbol (or prepend the pattern with `(?s)` inline modifier option - `(?s)(?<=wordA.*?)wordB(?=.*?wordD)`).

If the "words" consist of letters/digits/underscores, and you need to match them as whole words, do not forget to wrap the `wordA`, `wordB` and `wordD` with `\b`s (word boundaries).

Always test your regexes in the target environment:

```
var s = "wordA wordB wordC wordB \n wordD";
var pattern = @"(?<=wordA.*?)wordB(?=.*?wordD)";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, "<<<$&>>>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.WriteLine(result);
// => wordA <<<wordB>>> wordC <<<wordB>>> 
//    wordD
```

See [C# demo](http://ideone.com/iqL85L).

Comment: It works perfectly on the demo you gave. But I was trying similarly on regex101.com and there it was giving error. Is there difference between different online compilers? I saved the URL here  https://regex101.com/r/ORkgjg/1

Comment: @Utsav: Why are you using http://regex101.com to test a **.NET** regex if the Web site does not support .NET regex syntax? The question is tagged with C#. See a C# demo  I added to the answer.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you!