# regex check if text between two strings contains a certain word

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

Best Content Marketing Tips to Make Your Website Standout from the Rest

---

I need to find out with regex if text between the words "Best" and "Rest" contains word "marketing":

My formula is as follows: `(?<=Best|)(marketing?)(?=Rest)`.

This formula works only if I want to find a word exactly before the "Rest", which in this case is "the ".

How do I make it to search if any word between two specified strings matches my Keyword?

Comment: Maybe just `Best.*marketing.*Rest`? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587168/regular-expressions-match-specific-word-between-two-words (for .NET, `(?<=Best.*?)marketing(?=.*?Rest)`)

Comment: `(?=Best.*Rest)(?=.*( Marketing ))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
\b[Bb]est\b.*\b[Mm]arketing\b.*\b[Rr]est\b
```

or instead of character classes set case insensitive flag first:

```
(?i)\bbest\b.*\bmarketing\b.*\brest\b
```

I've used word boundaries just to prevent Best and Rest or Marketing from being substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a case-insensitive search for a regex pattern inside a string,
with the pattern having the word 'Best', then any number of any characters,
then a specified keyword (e.g. 'marketing'), then any number of any characters again, and finally the word 'Rest':

```
import re

text = "Best Content Marketing Tips to Make Your Website Standout from the Rest"

Keyword = "marketing"  # Customize your search-word here

pattern = re.compile(r"Best.*({}).*Rest".format(Keyword), re.I)
print("Found match in text: \n", pattern.search(text))

# See if your keyword was matched inside the searched text:
print("\nFound following keyword in text:\n", pattern.search(text).group(1))
```

Output:

```
Found match in text: 
 <re.Match object; span=(0, 71), match='Best Content Marketing Tips to Make Your Website >

Found following keyword in text:
 Marketing
```