# Sublime Text - REGEX: How to match a word in a string?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm using "find in Files" function of Sublime to search for a specific word in a specific string, that repeats on multiples files.

Something like that:

```
tags: TAG1 TAG2 TAG3 TAG4
alias: ALIAS1, ALIAS2`
```

I was Trying to find "TAG2", between "tags" and "alias", and was thinking on a REGEX Expression like this:

```
(?s)(?<=tags)TAG2(?=alias)
```

Inspired on this [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587168/regular-expressions-match-specific-word-between-two-words), but the REGEX syntax for Sublime is different and I've been unable to adapt it.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Is it always 2 lines? `^tags:.*\K\bTAG2\b(?=.*\Ralias:)` https://regex101.com/r/e62C2e/1 or a bit broader `(?s)\btags:.*\b\K\bTAG2\b(?=.*\salias:)` https://regex101.com/r/5aT8sO/1

Comment: Thx! Both versions worked great so far. Could you briefly explain what is the function of "\K" on those expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data with 2 lines:

```
^tags:.*\K\bTAG2\b(?=.*\Ralias:)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `tags:` Match literally
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far (so do not include in the match)
- `\bTAG2\b` Match the "word" TAG2 between word boundaries
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what to the right is

  - `.*\R` Match the rest or the line and a newline
  - `alias:` Match literally
- `)` Close the lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e62C2e/1)

**Note** that if you use `(?s)` the `.` will match any character including a newline, so `.*` can span multiple lines.